# Can a watchkit app launch itself like a notification at a specific time without ios App sending a localnotification?

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, watchkit

If I make a watchKit app, does the user have to run the app on ios for it to set off a timed notification on the watch? Is there a way to set the watchkit to just say "good morning" every morning at 8am without an ios app?

Comment: Based on apple's past behaviour, I would guess "No"

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best solution is to use localnotification from an ios app, at least with the current watchkit functionality available as of 4/3/15.

With a developer account, one can read here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html